# Saving heterogeneous object graph

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm

I have an unmanaged graph of objects. If I get objects without identity I can save them with:

```
$em->persist($obj);
```

But when I have one **with** identity (with `$obj->id` set) the `persist()` method wants to re-create it.  I realize that `merge()` is for cases like this. The only problem is that it's recursive (so every other object in the graph should also have identity) and my graph is heterogeneous in this aspect (some of them do others don't have their id's set).